# Trying to create new product type in magento, getting fatal error

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to create new product type in magento and it is showing up in admin panel create new product page's product type options, but when I select it and continue, i get fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setConfig() on a non-object in
>   /home/shop/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php
>   on line 82

Line 82 is:

```
$typeModel->setConfig($types[$typeId]);
```

Module config file (app/code/local/Pood/Toodep6hi/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>

        <modules>
            <Pood_Toodep6hi>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Pood_Toodep6hi>
        </modules>
        <adminhtml>
            <translate>
                <modules>
                    <Pood_Toodep6hi>
                    <files>
                        <default>Pood_Toodep6hi.csv</default>
                    </files>
                    </Pood_Toodep6hi>
                </modules>
            </translate>
        </adminhtml>


        <global>

            <models>
                <Toodep6hi>
                    <class>Pood_Toodep6hi_Model</class>
                </Toodep6hi>
            </models>

            <catalog>
                <product>
                    <type>
                        <p6hitoode translate="label" module="Toodep6hi">
                            <label>Pohitoode</label>
                            <model>Toodep6hi/Product_Type_P6hitoode</model>
                            <price_model>Toodep6hi/Product_Price</price_model>
                            <index_data_retreiver>Toodep6hi/catalogIndex_Data_P6hitoode</index_data_retreiver>
                            <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                        </p6hitoode>
                    </type>
                </product>
            </catalog>



            <helpers>
                <Toodep6hi>
                    <class>Pood_Toodep6hi_Helper</class>
                </Toodep6hi>
            </helpers>
        </global>
    </config>
```

app/code/local/Pood/Model/Product/Type/P6hitoode.php:

```
<?php
class Pood_Toodep6hi_Model_Product_Type_P6hitoode extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Toodep6hi_Type_Abstract
{
        const TYPE_P6HITOODE = "p6hitoode";
    public function isVirtual()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I found a sililar problem: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/196886/#t248371, but it did not help.

Every bit of help would be very appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show where you create $typeModel object?

Comment: Maybe you forget tu use namespace or include some file

Comment: Do i need to create $typeModel for my new product? I'm asking because for this new product I used this example shown here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/196886/#t248371 11th post. And I've checked twice if I forgot anything but didn't notice anything missing. Thank you!

Comment: Was this path a typo? app/code/local/Pood/Model/Product/Type/P6hitoode.php because it should be app/code/local/Pood/Toodep6hi/Model/Product/Type/P6hitoode.php. Also shouldn't you be extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract instead of  Mage_Catalog_Model_Toodep6hi_Type_Abstract?

Comment: Did this ever get fixed. having the same problem now...

Answer (score 2):

the problem is case sensititve

```
<model>Toodep6hi/product_type_p6hitoode</model>
```

it should be

```
<model>toodep6hi/product_type_p6hitoode</model>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend Mage_Catalog_Model_Toodep6hi_Type_Abstract from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Virtual

Answer (score 0):

Use lower case here:

```
<model>Toodep6hi/Product_Type_P6hitoode</model>
```

so it will be:

```
<model>Toodep6hi/product_type_p6hitoode</model>
```

If will not help, try to use lower case for model:

```
<models>
    <toodep6hi>
        <class>Pood_Toodep6hi_Model</class>
    </toodep6hi>
</models>
```

and lower case here then

```
<model>toodep6hi/product_type_p6hitoode</model>
```

Comment: Did not work, but thanks for trying. If I'm understanding it correctly the problem is that magento doesn't find my type class, if i type some random invalid syntax in my Type/P6hitoode.php, doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                <type>
                    <p6hitoode translate="label" module="Toodep6hi">
                        <label>Pohitoode</label>
                        <model>Toodep6hi/product_type_p6hitoode</model>
                        <price_model>Toodep6hi/product_price</price_model>
                        <index_data_retreiver>Toodep6hi/catalogIndex_data_p6hitoode</index_data_retreiver>
                        <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    </p6hitoode>
                </type>
```